# make the text fill the entire label width?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using C# and .Net in a windows form application
and I have an Index
this index is an array of lines each line is a label on the Form
each label width is the same and must be the same with the Form width
and this index must appear on my form like this :
[image: My form must look like this]
my problem is :
i want the the "text" to be exactly on the left and the the "number" to be exactly on the right
each line must be only one label
and the big problem is that each char have a different width so i can't know how much i must fill between the text and the number to make each label look exactly as I want

Comment: i think if i can measure the string length inside the label may be i will solve this problem...........is that true?and how can I measure the length of the string?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each line must be only one label

While I think using 2 labels per "line" would be more elegant, you could solve this by having your labels use a fixed width font.  This would make it so that each char was exactly the same width, and you could figure out how to "fill" appropriately.

Comment: I know it is better to use 2 labels but there is a reason that prevents me from that .............and where can I find fixed width font? what do you mean of that?

Comment: @ahmad: Use a font like "Courier New" that has a fixed width.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samples_of_monospaced_typefaces